RKHS of component-wise additive kernel
Given a kernel $k(x,y)$, for $x, y \in [a_j, b_j]^p \subset \mathbb{R}^p$, with its associated reproducible kernel Hilbert space $H_k$, let us assume $k(x, y) = k_1(x_1, y_1) + \cdots k_p(x_p, y_p)$. Here we assume $k_j(x_j, y_j)$ are all valid kernels in $[a_j, b_j]$. What can we say about the relationship between $H_k$ and $\{H_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^p$, where $H_{k_j}$ is the reproducible kernel Hilbert space associated with $k_j$. Note that each component-wise kernel can be defined at different intervals, so it is not as straightforward as adding two kernels of the same domain.
What are good references for this fact?
My guess is that it seems that $H_k$ is a direct sum of $\{H_{k_j}\}_{j=1}^p$, and wonder if there is any reference that delves into detail.

Yes, $H_k$ is the direct sum of the $H_{k_j}$, see eg Theorem 5 in the book by Berlinet and Thomas-Agnan. You will see there that there is a potential subtlety in how the norm in the new space is related to the component norms if the component spaces have nontrivial intersections.
